# How to access data from scope object to directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a code where  I need to return the array value of mydata but as I am out of for loop the array value is undefined even if I have defined it within the scope.
However I am able to see the value on view page using {{mydata}} but not able to access the same into the directive.
Controller Code:-

```
           angular.module('myApp.MyController', []);

                   myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, API_URL) {
                    $scope.mydata = [];
                   $http.get(API_URL).success(function(response) {
                   var data = response.result;

                   for (property in data ) {
                     $scope.mydata.push(data[property]);

                   }
                 });

                 console.log($scope.mydata);

                  });
```

Directive code :--

```
                         angular.module('myApp.barsChart',[]).


                            directive('barsChart', function ($parse) {

                              var directiveDefinitionObject = {

                                  restrict: 'E',

                                  replace: false,

                                  scope: {data: '=chartData'},
                                  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                                    var chart = d3.select(element[0]);

                                     chart.append("div").attr("class", "chart")
                                      .selectAll('div')
                                      .data(scope.data).enter().append("div")
                                      .transition().ease("elastic")
                                      .style("width", function(d) { return d + "%"; })
                                      .text(function(d) { return d + "%"; });

                                  } 
                               };
                               return directiveDefinitionObject;
                            });
```

View Page code:-

```
<bars-chart chart-data="mydata"></bars-chart>
    <p>{{mydata}} new data is </p>
```

Comment: It is outside of the `$http.get`. It is an asynchronous function which returns later when api sends the response. By the time `console.log($scope.mydata);` is executed which is `undefined`

Comment: The console.log is outside the callback and will run prior to the async call returning.  How are you using it on your page?

Comment: @NeelShah, Why do you need that ? Data is there under the `$scope`, bind it in view or if you want to manipulate it then do it in `success` callback itself..

Comment: @George Houpis :  I want to use this data Into directive to use it properly. I have updated my questions by including the view page and the directive as well. I am not able to pass the data to directive. while on view page I acn acces the data using {{mydata}} syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
               angular.module('myApp.MyController', []);

               myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, API_URL) {
                $scope.mydata = [];
               $http.get(API_URL).success(function(response) {
               var data = response.result;

               for (property in data ) {
                 $scope.mydata.push(data[property]);

               }
               console.log($scope.mydata);

             });


              });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
 $rootScope variable instead of $scope
 as

```
               myApp.controller('MyController', function($rootScope, $http, API_URL) {
                $rootScope.mydata = [];
               $http.get(API_URL).success(function(response) {
               var data = response.result;

               for (property in data ) {
                 $rootScope.mydata.push(data[property]);

               }
             });

             console.log($rootScope.mydata);

              });
```

and you can access this variable any controller of your js file

Comment: I don't want to use $rootScope on my controller.